# Emacs shell mode problem

Tags: shell, emacs

While emacs shell mode when I run

```
ls
```

I get following

```
   [0m[01;32mmanage.py[0m     [01;34mtemplates[0m
```

these must be manage.py and templates. Why its like that and how can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put ~/.emacs

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

and it solved my problem. Anyway thanks for answering. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704616/something-wrong-with-emacs-shell) that solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Those are vt100 codes for color display (which is usually enabled by default on most Linux distros today).  Emacs shell doesn't handle the vt100 escape codes.

Find out whether your `ls` command is aliased.

```
which ls
```

Does it look like like the following or something similar?

```
ls: alias to ls --color=tty
```

If so you'll need to find where this alias is set and unalias it or change how it is called.

Your shell knows it is running in an emacs shell if the EMACS environment setting is set to `t`.  You can do something like the following to set alternate functions.  I use zsh, so this contains some items specific to that shell.

```
## for emacs
if [[ $EMACS = "t" ]] then
   PROMPT="%# "  # make the prompt simple
   unsetopt zle  # turn off advanced line editting

   ls_pager=( cat ) # ls is simple piped to cat
   ls_flags=( -A )  # default ls flags
fi
```

For bash you can you just alias ls

```
alias ls='ls -A'
```

Comment: +1 (Beat me, I was just typing in the same) But not as detailed...

Comment: which ls
/bin/ls
I use bash and  putting 
alias ls='ls -A'
did not worked